# Changing Token Limit Dynamically on add function of jquery token input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I need to change the token limit of a token input textbox dynamically based on its add and on delete functions. In my case when the user selects an item called "all users" from the list, the token limit should change to 1 and when the same is removed it should be again null.

Comment: Can you add what you've tried? You seem to have the logic correct - so if you add what you've tried, hopefully it will be easier to point out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: I also have same problem anyone have solution ?

Comment: @Chris i have same problem like this can u help me out to solve this ?