# How to change Token Limit Dynamically in onadd function of jquery token input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

Same problem as [Changing Token Limit Dynamically on add function of jquery token input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28474159/4762957)

I need to change the token limit of a token input textbox dynamically based on its add and on delete functions.  In my case when the user selects an item called "text" from the list, the token limit should change to 1 otherwise null.

```
  $("[id$=searchbox]").tokenInput(itemsArray, 
  {
         onAdd: function(item) 
         {     
              //What to write here to set token limit 
         }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [sources](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js#L564) you find out that the `tokenLimit` setting is always read from `$(input).data("settings").tokenLimit`.

This means you can also set it from outside at any time.

```
$("[id$=searchbox]").tokenInput(itemsArray, {
     onAdd: function(item) {
         if(!$("[id$=searchbox]").data("settings")) {
             $("[id$=searchbox]").data("settings", {});
         }
         $("[id$=searchbox]").data("settings").tokenLimit = 10;
     }
});
```

Now add your custom logic.

Comment: It gives me 'JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'tokenLimit' of undefined or null reference ' error

Comment: That's because you are not passing any "settings" to the initial `tokenInput` call so the plugin does not initialize it. See my updated answer - or maybe initialize it with something - an initial `tokenLimit` value should work.